# AJAX upload form?

Tags: ajax, upload

I want to make AJAX upload form (for images). I made the form, PHP code and it work with refresh but I want to make it with ajax. All data is in $_FILE array (PHP) but I don't know how to get it in javascript. Can you help me?
I tried to make something with $.post and $.ajax (jQuery) but i can't get the data. :\

Answer (score 0):

there is many javascript plugin for upload files 
you can try these :

[Ajax File Upload Plugin](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/)

[Multiple File Upload Plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/)

[valums](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader)

Comment: Thank you, but this is my homework and I can't use plugins. I must make form, php code (done) and ajax.